# Mikro ORM validation errors not catched

Tags: validation, websocket, socket.io, nestjs, mikro-orm

I have the following function:

```
 @SubscribeMessage('sendMessage')
  async handleSendMessage(
    _: Socket,
    payload: CreateMessageInput,
  ): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const created = this.em.create(Chat, {
        text: payload.text,
        user: payload.userId,
      });
      this.em.persistAndFlush(created);

      const { userName } = await this.em.findOneOrFail(User, {
        id: payload.userId,
      });

      this.server.emit('receiveMessage', {
        text: payload.text,
        user: { userName, id: payload.userId },
      });
    } catch (e) {
      if (e.name === 'NotFoundError') {
        throw new NotFoundException('User not found.');
      }
      throw new InternalServerErrorException('Something went wrong');
    }
  }
```

If I omit the user when testing this function, Im getting  `ValidationError: Value for Chat.user is required, 'undefined' found` , but this error is not being catched by my catch clause, resulting in the socket hanging. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an await in there:

```
const created = this.em.create(Chat, {
  text: payload.text,
  user: payload.userId,
});
await this.em.persistAndFlush(created); // <--
```

Also note that you don't have to persist entities created via `em.create`, that happens automatically in current versions, so calling `em.flush()` is enough here.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info! When would persistAndFlush be properly used?

Comment: It's fine to do it, but you don't have to (its a no-op, as the entity is already marked for persistence). It's a shortcut for `persist` followed by `flush`, so when you need to call `persist`, that's where you need to do it. That's basically only when you create the entity instance manually, via constructor.